# An orthogonal matrix that satisfies a property must be a permutation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ orthogonal matrix such that $\sum_{k=1}^na_{ik}^3a_{jk}=\sum_{k=1}^na_{jk}^3a_{ik}$ for every $1\le i,j\le n$.

Original question which is solved by a counterexample given (For the new question see Edit 2): 
I want to show that $A$ is either a permutation matrix (i.e., all but one entry in each row and column is zero, and that non-zero entry is $1$ or $-1$), or all entries of $A$ have absolute value $1/\sqrt n$.

This question happens in my calculation on some functions from the tangent space of $A$.

I will provide a proof of $n=2$ without using the $\sin$ & $\cos$ representation of $A$:

$a_{11}^3a_{21}+a_{12}^3a_{22}=a_{11}a_{21}^3+a_{12}a_{22}^3$, so $a_{11}a_{21}(a_{11}^2-a_{21}^2)=a_{12}a_{22}(a_{22}^2-a_{12}^2)$. Since they are unit vectors, $a_{11}^2-a_{21}^2=a_{22}^2-a_{12}^2$, so it's easy to deduce the desired result. However, I find it hard to generalize this method.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Edit: Ok let's add the condition that $\sum_{k=1}^na_{ki}^3a_{kj}=\sum_{k=1}^na_{kj}^3a_{ki}$ for every $1\le i,j\le n$. I have proved that this must be true from the assumptions.

Edit 2: the comment gives a counterexample of this. As Ilya Bogdanov suggested, it is true that if $A$ is irreducible, then each non-zero entry of $A$ has the same absolute value?

Comment: @LSpice The tangent space of $A$ in the manifold $O(n)$, which is $A$ times all skew symmetric matrices, and from that (and my original problem) I got this question.

Comment: I see.  I believe that the usual grammar is "the tangent space *at* $A$ *to* $\operatorname O(n)$."

Comment: You say "I have proved that this must be true from the assumptions", which suggests that there's a real problem behind this one that you're not specifying.  Why not say what that is?

Comment: @LSpice What I meant is from the assumption of $\sum_{k=1}^na_{ik}^3a_{jk}=\sum_{k=1}^na_{jk}^3a_{ik}$.

Comment: What if you take the direct sum of a (normalised) 2x2 Hadamard and a 2x2 identity matrix?

Comment: @PadraigÓCatháin Well you find a counterexample. Thanks!

Comment: So, @Padraig's comment siggests that any direct sum of normalized Hadamard matrices, with rows and columns being permuted arbitrarily, works. Perhaps, it is better to ask about irreducible matrices...

Comment: Check out weighing matrices -- they are nxn orthogonal matrices with k non-zero entries in each row and column. There should be also lots of irreducible examples of these.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the matrix below is perhaps too large for a comment.

It seems that here is an irreducible counterexample:
$$
  \frac12\begin{bmatrix}
    1& 1& -1& 1& 0& 0& 0& \cdots& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
    1& 1& 1& -1& 0& 0& 0& \cdots& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
    0& 0& 1& 1& -1& 1& 0& \cdots& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
    0& 0& 1& 1& 1& -1& 0& \cdots& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
    \vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \ddots& \vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \vdots\\
    0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& \cdots& 0& 1& 1& 1& -1\\
    -1& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& \cdots& 0& 0& 0& 1& 1\\
    1& -1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& \cdots& 0& 0& 0& 1& 1\\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
Surely, one can find many more similar examples.

So I would ask whether all *nonzero* elements of an *irreducible* orthogonal matrix satisfying the property have the same absolute value.